# Telegram bot keyboard PHP

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I have written this function for my telegram bot in PHP but it doesn't work:

```
if($text == "t"){
    $keyboard = array(
        "inline_keyboard" => array(
            array(
                array(
                    "text" => "My Button Text", 
                    "callback_data" => "myCallbackData"
                )
            )
        )
    );
    $key = array(
        "keyboard" => $keyboard,
    );
    keyboard($chatId, "asadsd", $key);
}
function keyboard($chatID, $text, $t)
{
    $t2 = $t;
    $t3 = json_encode($t2);

    api("sendMessage?chat_id=$chatId&text=$text&parse_mode=HTML&reply_markup=$t3");        
}
```

It should work but it is not doing so.

How can I fix this? ([me](https://t.me/ace_69) and [my bot](https://t.me/Ace_69_bot))

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: Pro-tip: titles are best phrased as a plain English summary of your problem, or a short question that summarises your problem. "Telegram bot keyboard PHP" is a collection of themes/tags, but is not very descriptive about the issue itself.

Comment: Ace, please always respond to requests for clarification here. @Jason's message seems to have gone unreplied to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you are trying to put the inline_keyboard array into a classic keyboard array. So:

- Remove `$key = array(...);` and when you're calling the keyboard function put `$keyboard` instead of `$key` .
- Put `$chatID` instead of `$chatId` in the keyboard function because php variable names are case-sensitive.
- Remove the `$t2` and `$t3` since they are useless.
- I suggest putting an arguments variable and using `http_build_query` to build the args, so it will automatically urlencode and build the vars.

Your code should result like this:

```
if($text == "t"){
    $keyboard = array(
        "inline_keyboard" => array(
            array(
                array(
                    "text" => "My Button Text", 
                    "callback_data" => "myCallbackData"
                )
            )
        )
    );

    keyboard($chatId, "asadsd", $keyboard);
}
function keyboard($chatID, $text, $t)
{
    $args = array(
        "chat_id" => $chatID,
        "text" => $text,
        "parse_mode" => "HTML",
        "reply_markup" => json_encode($t),
    );
    api("sendMessage?".http_build_query($args));        
}
```

Assuming everything is set, the code should work fine. Next time, please, be more specific